Integration test java spring: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
I want to write Integration logic and endpoints and doesn't want to mock any class, but the program doesn't get into service layer, and gives the error of :
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'service.index.service.IndexService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

if I mockBean the service class, it gives 200 status code. while I need to also test the service layer as well and not mock it away. if it gets into service and do all the logic part, it should gives out 201 status code.
How can I make it so it test the whole part from controller and the service layer as well?
This is the Test:
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class)
class ControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;

@Autowired
private IndexService indexService;

private String baseUrl = "https://localhost/";

@Test
void createIndex() throws Exception {

    CreationInputDto input = new CreationInputDto();

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(
            post(baseUrl+"/create")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(input))
            )
            .andExpect(status().is(201))
            .andReturn();


    String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
}}

My IndexService has several autowired parameters which several of them are interfaces and can't be initiated easily.
Update: Thanks everyone. I tried SpringBootTest and WebTestClient instead and it was successful. I put the code, in case in future someone had the same problem and wanted to use the WebTestClient:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebTestClient webTestClient;

@Test
void createIndex() {
    
    CreationInputDto input = new CreationInputDto();

    WebTestClient.ResponseSpec result = webTestClient
            .post()
            .uri("/create")
            .body(Mono.just(input), CreationInputDto.class)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isEqualTo(201);
}}


The problem is that you are using the @WebMvcTest annotation without making the origin of the Index Service Bean explicit. When using this annotation, Spring Boot loads the application in a context to include only components related to MVC, however, this configuration does not load beans that are not directly linked to MVC.
As you can see in the documentation, it is highly recommended to use this testing configuration in conjunction with @MockBean or @Import, depending on your needs.
Using MockBean, you can mock your Bean and within the test create isolated behavior for calling some function:
@MockBean
private IndexService indexService;

Then inside of your test:
when(indexService.createIndex(any(CreationInputDto.class))).thenReturn(/*appropriate response*/);

With @Import, you can simply import the Bean in question into your test context using the annotation in your class.
@Import(IndexService.class)


I don't think that this is what Bahar wants, since he wrote "I need to also test the service layer as well and not mock it away".

So wouldn't it be more sensible to just use @SpringBootTest instead of @WebMvcTest?

Yes, indeed, as suggested also in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mockmvc-vs-webmvctest, but in this case you also may need to have a test database (real or an h2 that is istantiated on the fly by test context).

Thanks. I will try SpringBootTest and WebClient to see if it would work

I think your question is similar to Add one additional bean to "@WebMvcTest".
There are multiple ways to add your bean into slice test context. You can use @Import, @ComponentScan, @TestConfiguration (and create your bean by yourself with new operator).

thank you for your response. with Import, it gives the error of : Failed to instantiate [service.index.respository.IndexRepository]: Specified class is an interface
and for TestConfiguration, I can't initiate the same interface class, since it's interface.

When you used the Import to make the IndexService being injected into the test class, did you also add the needed @Autowired beans as @MockBean in the ControllerTest class?

@FrancescoPoli If I add @MockBean, it mock the classes, I need the real classes, since I am writing integration test and need all of them to function and not be mocked

@Bahar so you need to also have the "real" IndexRepository, InputRepository, etc?

@FrancescoPoli yes, all of them

Repositories are actual classes or interfaces extening of JpaRepository? Because in this case you can actually use these as mocks, and import the real mappers (are them Mapstruc based?).

they are interfaces from JpaRepository and mappers are also from Mapstruct based

@Bahar, could you explain why you want to use @WebMvcTest in favor of @SpringBootTest if you need “integration” testing with your entire Depencency hierarchy?
Think about split your case into 2 parts - testing mvc layer with mocks and a IndexService with all dependencies. So, if you still want to use WebMvcTest with real IndexService, you should build them manually.

I add here some more references, besides what it has been written in the comments section, in the case you decide to use an hybrid integration approach, that uses real service and mappers, but mocked repositories.
For the mappers, you can write an additional @Configuration class like this:
@Configuration
public class MapperTestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  CreationInputMapper creationInputMapper() {
    return Mappers.getMapper(CreationInputMapper.class);
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  IndexMapper indexMapper() {
    return Mappers.getMapper(IndexMapper.class);
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  IndexshareMapper indexshareMapper() {
    return Mappers.getMapper(IndexshareMapper.class);
  }
}

This class can be included by the ControllerTest for context creation relying on the @Import annotation already used for the service.
Since the repositories are JpaRepository extension, you can use a @MockBean approach (and then use the when clause suggested), or create an in memory h2 / hsqldb database specifically crafted for tests (in this case, you have to provide the schema.sql and data.sql for inizialization), or use a real db.
